# OpenModelica "Change" block does not work properly. [Beginner]

Tags: modelica, openmodelica

I am really new on Modelica in general but I have a project I need to finish really soon. I apologize if something that I say is really basic. I have tried a few tweaks and searched over the internet but I cannot seem to figure out how to do this to work.

I have created a model. Inside there is a block with a boolean output, lets call this output boolean variable `Y1`.

Connected to that block I use the `Modelica.Blocks.Logical.Change` or the `Modelica.Blocks.MathBoolean.ChangingEdge` blocks. I have tried both since if I understand correctly they do the same thing. `Y1` is the input of this block.

So basically the moment when `Y1` changes from `true` to `false` or from `false` to `true` the output of the `Change` block (lets call it `Y2`) should be `true` just for that timestep.

This does not happen. `Y2` is constantly on `false`. I have checked and `Y1` is changing over time.

I have also tried to run the example `Modelica.Blocks.Examples.BooleanNetwork1` but I see the same thing in there also. The desired output does not change to the example either.

For reference I use the OpenModelica 1.17 with Modelica Standard Library 3.2.3. These are the versions I am obligated to use and I cannot use newer or older ones.

Any tip would be highly appreciated! Thank you.

---

PS If this does not work I would like to use something different. Is there a way I can access all the previous values (history) of `Y1` inside an another block and find these changes with an algorithm there? So lets say I am on timestep N and inside a block I want to access `Y1` from 0 to N-1 and find the last timestep that Y1 has changed.

Answer (score 2):

How did you check that the output of the `change` block doesn't fire at the events? You may not be able to see it on a plot since the impulse is 'infinitely' short (at least, that's my experience with Dymola).

You could latch the impulse from the `change` block by connecting it's output to an SR flipflop.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. You might be right about that. But what I was thinking is that first the plot is automatically scaled with the values of the variable and the range is too short ( 0 to 0.4 if I remember correctly), meaning that no higher values exist except zero. Second I tried to zoom as far as I could and I did not notice anything. not even a simple spike.

Comment: Don't trust the plots. See also the question https://stackoverflow.com/q/68953428/8725275. Hans has a very good explanation why you cannot see the change.

Comment: Thank you both for your help! Indeed the block was working and the plots were untrustworthy. I was able to capture it with the help of additional blocks such as `Modelica.Blocks.MathInteger.TriggeredAdd` .