# Equation in if branch is not executed

Tags: if-statement, equation, modelica

I have a question that confused me for a long time. As you know, when we use an if condition in Modelica, that means if the expression is true, then Modelica will do the corresponding equation.
But when i test the following code, I am confused:

```
model Model134
  Real a(start = 0);
equation 
  if not sample(0, 2) then 
    a = 1;
  else
    a = 3;
  end if;
end Model134;
```

I think `a` will be changed every 2s (start time=0), but when I simulate this model, it dose not change and `a` is equal to 1 all the time.

Dose anybody know the root cause?

Answer (score 4):

`a` does change its value, but depending on your simulation tool you might not see it in the plot.

`sample(0, 2)` creates a time event every 2 seconds. The return value of `sample()` is only true during the event. So the value of `a` changes, but after the event it immediately changes back.

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68953808/8725275) to a similar question, it is mentioned that Dymola stores the value before and after the event in result file. Intermediate values are skipped for efficiency reasons (there can be many for every event, which would bloat up your result file). Hence you can not plot this change in Dymola. For OpenModelica see the [answer by
Akhil Nandan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74262999/8725275).

To proof that `a` really does change its value you can use this code for example:

```
model Model134
  import Modelica.Utilities.Streams.print;
  Real a;
equation 
  if sample(0, 2) then
    a = 1;
  else
    a = 0;
  end if;

  when a > 0.5 then
    print("a is " + String(a) + " at t=" + String(time) + "s");
  end when;

  annotation (experiment(StopTime=10));
end Model134;
```

You should see something like this in the simulation log:

```
a is 1 at t=2s
a is 1 at t=4s
a is 1 at t=6s
a is 1 at t=8s
a is 1 at t=10s
```

Comment: that is a good idea with when code to prove the event

Answer (score 3):

[image]

This is the plot simulated when trying your above code in `OpenModelica` with settings shown in the second figure.

[image]

A `time event` is triggered when `sample(startTime,interval)` evaluates `true` at every multiple of 2 seconds and based on your code logic this should activate `else`
block and assign value of variable `a` to be 3.

Comment: thanks! a is changed at the time point . the period is too short too print the result in Modelica

Comment: Cheers! Hope it worked for you